# Solution to get voice along with video stream in Amazon Kinesis Video Streams

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am able to stram video content in KVS but without voice. Anyone have idea about to get voice along with vide stream ?

I am following below reference.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producersdk-android-downloadcode.html
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp

Answer (score 0):

the android producer currently dont support audio video ingestion. But if you can generate the mkv yourself using something like ffmpeg, then you can send it through putMedia directly.

Comment: is there any reference available to check ? 
# Android Code